# Add Hyperlink To Body Of Email In Apex Code

Tags: apex, hyperlink

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to a string which will form the body of an email that I'm sending from an Apex class.

```
subject = 'Please give us your feedback';
body = '<html lang="ja"><body>'+
       '<br><br>'+'Dear '+FirstName+
       '<br><br>'+'Some text'+
       '<br><br>'+'we’d like to complete a short survey.'+
       '<br><br>'+<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk">Take the survey now.</a>+
                        '<br><br>'+'Kind regards,'+
                        '<br>'+'Company Name';
```

But I'm getting an error:

> unexpected token: '<'

at the line `'<br><br>'+<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk">Take the survey now.</a>+`

I've found plenty of examples which demonstrate how to [include hyperlinks in VisualForce emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/30733/10720) but none when the string is in a standard Apex class, is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using

```
'<br><br>'+<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk">Take the survey now.</a>+
```

try to add your link inside single quote like

```
'<br><br><a href="https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk">Take the survey now.</a>'+
```

Comment: @AlexS awesome.. :)

Comment: This answer is the reason why I prefer to use Dom.Document to form well-structured XML or HTML.